# What sort of rock climbing grade can a goat do?

Tags: rock-climbing, animal-behaviour

It is quite well known that goats are into [free solo rock climbing](https://imgur.com/gallery/ddcWE). Is there any evidence (even if anecdotal) of the highest [grades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_%28climbing%29) they are able to climb?

Comment: Goats are good, really good, at rock climbing.  They don't need no stink'n grades!

Comment: @Arjun: I have seen goats climbing at amazing places in Sahyadris, Western Ghats, India. Though I can' specify the grades right away, I am so sure that they can climb so well on tough routes for hours.

Comment: More important is about fast they move on the grades they do climb.

Comment: I don't think this question is as unanswerable as some say... route grading is somewhat subjective but there is an upper limit on what a goat can achieve, and one could grade that route. Therefore, it should be possible (albeit difficult) to determine what the most difficult route is that a goat can climb. Sure, they climb it differently from humans, but that isn't the question.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently [Galen Rowell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galen_Rowell) took a picture of a goat in the Cirque of the Unclimbables mantling past Galen's rappel anchors with a grade (US) of 5.9+.

Comment: Thank you for tracking this down. Google also pointed me to [this](http://www.supertopo.com/climbers-forum/2249521/How-hard-on-the-YDS-scale-can-goats-climb) relevant rock climbing forum thread.

Comment: @ArjunShankar so many good goat photos!

Comment: I am a huge fan.